# Problem in undersanding notation of distributional section

Tags: distribution-theory, vector-bundles

In this   post  [Observables](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-observables/) By Urs Schreiber he denotes   the space of distributional sections

let $\Gamma_{\Sigma}^{\prime}\left(E^*\right):=\left(\Gamma_{\Sigma, c p}(E)\right)^*$ in the  definition 7.9
That is if $u \in \Gamma_{\Sigma}^{\prime}\left(E^*\right) $  than $u$ is a linear functional that takes as argument sections of a vector bundle $E$

$ u_{(b)} \in \Gamma_{\Sigma, s}^{\prime}(E^*)$

In the same post he has  proposition 7.10

> Let $E \stackrel{f b}{\rightarrow} \Sigma$ be a smooth vector bundle over Minkowski spacetime and let $s \in\{c p, \pm c p, s c p, t c p\}$ be any of the support conditions from def. $2.36$.
> Then the operation of regarding a compactly supported smooth section of the dual vector bundle as a functional on sections with this support property is a dense subspace inclusion into the topological vector space of distributional sections from def. 7.9:
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \Gamma_{\Sigma, \mathrm{cp}}\left(E^*\right) & \stackrel{u_{(-)}}{\longrightarrow} & \Gamma_{\Sigma, S}^{\prime}(E) \\
> b & \mapsto & \left(\Phi \mapsto \int_{\Sigma} b(x) \cdot \Phi(x) \operatorname{dvol}_{\Sigma}(x)\right)
> \end{array}
> $$

In my understanding $u_{()}$ is a map from the space of sections of the dual bundle to the space of the distributional section .

Why  $ u_{()} \in \Gamma_{\Sigma, s}^{\prime}(E)$ ? Shouldn't we have $ u_{()} \in \Gamma_{\Sigma, s}^{\prime}(E^*)$

Answer (score 1):

To me this appears as a typo, $\Gamma_{\Sigma,s}'(E)$ is not even defined around there and if the author means something else like $\Gamma_{\Sigma,s}'((E^*)^*)$ I would at least have expected a note.

The space $(\Gamma_{\Sigma,cp}(E))^*$ may be seen as "distributions on sections in $E$", suggesting the notation $\Gamma_{\Sigma}'(E)$, or as sections in $E^*$ which are not smooth, but "at most distributional", suggesting to denote it $\Gamma_{\Sigma}'(E^*)$. I guess the author just mixed them up.